# Is a list implementation faster than a dictionary implementation?

Tags: python, pyside

I have a UI I wrote that in which I place all my widgets in a list through a list comprehension. I had originally attempted to place everything in a dictionary comprehension so that everything would have a label.

```
widgets = [
    QtGui.QLineEdit(),
    QtGui.QSpinBox(),
    QtGui.QLabel("-"),
    QtGui.QSpinBox(),
    QtGui.QPushButton("Export"),
    QtGui.QPushButton("Del")
]
```

as opposed to

```
widgets = {
    "textField":QtGui.QLineEdit(),
    "minFrame":QtGui.QSpinBox(),
    "dash":QtGui.QLabel("-"),
    "maxFrame":QtGui.QSpinBox(),
    "exportButton":QtGui.QPushButton("Export"),
    "delButton":QtGui.QPushButton("Del")
}
```

My question here is why is it that when I implement the dictionary, the order of the elements seems to mix up. So when I loop through to add them to the layout like so:

```
for w in widgets: # or widgets.values() for the dic
    mainLayout.addWidget(w)
```

It seems like the dictionary is slower to initialize all the objects than a list.

Comment: If you want order in your dict, use an OrderedDict, I asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-is-arbitrary

Comment: Dictionaries are slower to create than lists, but the difference is in nanoseconds (billions of a second). If you want to speed things up, look elsewhere.

Comment: Use `timeit.Timer` if you want to see what's faster. Especially if you've already written both versions.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I looked into that OrderedDict, worked like a charm I totally forgot about those. I'm also gonna look into how the hash tables are implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `[1, 2, 3]` is a list literal. It is *not* list comprehension that might look like `[x for x in something]` (see the `for`-loop inside)
- the same for `dict`s: `{1:2, 3:4}` is an ordinary dict literal. It is *not* dict comprehension that might look like `{k:v for k, v in pairs}` (again, see the `for`-loop inside)

> My question here is why is it that when I implement the dictionary, the order of the elements seems to mix up.

The order of elements in a dictionary may change from run to run. Don't rely on it. You could use a list of pairs or `collections.OrderedDict` depending on your case.

> It seems like the dictionary is slower to initialize all the objects than a list.

I'd expect `for w in widgets` to be faster if `widgets` is a list compared to `for w in widget.values()` where `widgets` is a dictionary. But given the code for `widgets` in your question; it is unlikely that it is a bottleneck in your application regardless whether you use a list or a dictionary to store a few widgets.

Comment: Yes, I had gone with the `collections.OrderedDict` and that worked nicely. Thank you for clarifying the difference between literals and comprehensions. And it wasn't a bottleneck at all, I had tried also doing `widgets = self.widgets.values()` (since this is within a class) and there was no difference.